# Android Facebook event request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an app, which should request events from Facebook.

I get the Message:

> {Response: responseCode:200, graphObject: null, error{HttpStatus:-1, errorCode:-1, errorType:null, errorMessage:com.facebook.FacebookException:Session provided to a Request in un-opened state.}, isFromCache:false}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, container, false);
    
    requestData();
    
    eventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
    eventOrt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventOrt);
    eventZeit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventZeit);
    eventBeschreibung = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventBeschreibung);
    
    
    return view;

}

private void requestData(){
    
    Request request = new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(), 
            "/0keepyourself/events", 
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Object obj = response;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (CharSequence) response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
    String test = (String) request.getParameters().get("name");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
}
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, Thank you it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Session provided to a Request in un-opened state

You need to call `openForRead()` first, check if the state of the access token is `OPENED` and then call `request.executeAsync()`.